# Jenkins GitBlit integration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, gitblit

I am performing POC for my company using Jenkins, GitBlit integration.

I have installed GitBlit & Jenkins and followed below steps

1. Installed Jenkins & GitBlit
2. used authority.cmd for generating self signed certificate for using my ip address
3. created a ruby cucumber project in gitblit
4. in the edit -> receive selection of GitBlit repository added jenkins for pre-receive scripts
5. in the gitblit-1.7.1\data\groovy i have added my jenkins which is again hosted on localhost

here are my urls

```
Jenkins :- http://localhost:8080/

GitBlit :- https://--.--.---.100:8443

GitBlit repo url :- https://--.--.---.100:8443/r/testGit.git
```

6. in jenkins, i have created freestyle project
7. in the source code management added repo url

i am facing issue here jenkins is not able to connect and below is the error message and screenshot

```
 Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-    remote -h https://--.--.---.100:8443/r/testGit.git HEAD" returned status code   128:
 stdout: 
 stderr: fatal: unable to access   'https://--.--.---.100:8443/r/testGit.git/': SSL certificate problem: self    signed certificate in certificate chain
```

[image: jenkins error message]

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are...

1. Switch to http:// rather than https://
2. Switch to ssh:// rather than https://
3. Switch to git:// rather than https://
4. Purchase a signed SSL certificate
5. Instruct Jenkins Git to not verify certificates

Comment: 1. how can we instruct jenkins and git not to verify certificates

2. what is security concern using it

Comment: "git config http.sslVerify false"  Security concern can easily be researched without re-writing here.